# Show index of tabs in the tabline

Tags: plugin-airline

I want when i type `:tabnew` , that it automatically create numbered (indexed) tabs according to which tab in order it is.
if it's 3rd tab that will be opened, than to show number 3 before tab name ( `3 [tab name]` )

I can create tab with some name, like `:tabnew hello`
but number is still staying **1**
( `1 [tab name1]  | 1 [tab name2]  | 1 [tab name3]` )

I want it to show like index, so I can quickly jump to it with `<n>gt`
( `1 [tab name1]  | 2 [tab name2]  | 3 [tab name3]` )

so i can just jump without counting which tab it is, to 3rd from 1st, with `3gt`

If I disable vim airline, then with [this](https://superuser.com/a/477221) function I get that functionality, but airline is overshadowing it, so it's useless with airline enabled.

screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

---

environment:

vim: 9.0

vim-airline: 0.11

OS: Manjaro latest

airline configuration:

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_extensions = ['tabline']
let g:airline_highlighting_cache = 1
let g:airline_theme='wombat'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1           " enable airline tabline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_close_button = 0 " remove 'X' at the end of the tabline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_min_count = 2     " minimum of 2 tabs needed to display the tabline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_splits = 0       " disables the buffer name that displays on the right of the tabline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
```

terminal: xfce terminal 1.0.4

$TERM variable: xterm-256color

color configuration (:set t_Co?): t_Co=256

Comment: I suspect the number you are seeing is the number of splits.

Answer (score 2):

So, the solution is to include this in vimrc

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_nr_type = 1 " tab number
```